# Asynchronous page update with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

I'm learning ASP.NET MVC 1.0 and need to implement an asynchronous/dynamic page update. I'm new to MVC and jQuery so I'm not sure what to look for.

What I want to do is to allow a user to start a monitoring a domain layer function (similar to a news ticker) and then do a partial page update based on the continously changing results.

In ASP.NET I'd do this with a javascript timer to cause a postback, and an AJAX update panel..... but this seems a bit "hacky" for ASP.NET MVC. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

Get the [jQuery Timers plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/timers), which will make it much simpler to set up timers, and do a regular [$.get(url, data, callback)](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) or [$('#myupdatepanel").load(url, data)](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

You can recreate an "update panel" easily by using these jQuery methods.